# Typo3: caching between controller and HTML template

Tags: typo3

I have a controller which assigns data to the view via `$this->view->assign('groups', $groups);`

Those 'groups' are processed in the HTML template. Now if I'm not mistaken it **must be** that typo3 caches the whole computation flow of the controller somewhere. Because when I change those 'groups', they are not recomputed, meaning the HTML template does not get updated data. However if I change the HTML template directly, I see the updates. It's just that computation of 'groups' in the controller which doesn't get updated. How can I prevent typo3 from caching that whole cascade of "controller computes data and assigns them to the view"?

Comment: I found the exact cause: when you use configurePlugin you need to use the second array in the arguments list to define a non-cachable action.

Comment: Here is configuration for non-cachable action https://github.com/GhanshyamBhava/imageuploader/blob/master/ext_localconf.php#L15-L17